# How to update html with js object values

Tags: css, html, sass

This might not be a recommended question to ask as i am not supplying code examples, but i am trying to replicate the design in the image below. I am looking for somewhere with an example of the layout so i can copy the HTML and CSS straight from it (4 boxes aligned with 1 big box) can anyone point me in the right direction or what technology i can look at? I have looked at css-grid but i am struggling to find a similar example of what i am looking for?

[image]
Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you look at the source for that page?

Comment: It's an image mate

Answer (score 1):

Try using Bootstrap. This layout will be very easy to develop using Bootstrap's two column layout.

Answer (score 0):

CSS Grid should be able to do the trick.  Quick whip up below, you can obviously adjust the column and row gaps as well as add the 100% row at the bottom for the red button in your example... this should be a good starting point for you though.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="Header">
    <div class="TopHeader" style="background-color:red;">
    </div>
    <div class="BottomHeader" style="background-color:blue;">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="LeftCol" ">
    <div class="Square1 " style="background-color:orange; "></div>
    <div class="Square2 " style="background-color:green; "></div>
    <div class="Square3 " style="background-color:orange; "></div>
    <div class="Square4 " style="background-color:green; "></div>
  </div>

  <div class="RightCol " style="background-color:yellow; ">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.TopHeader {
  grid-area: topheader;
}

.BottomHeader {
  grid-area: bottomheader;
}

.Square1 {
  grid-area: square1;
}

.Square2 {
  grid-area: square2;
}

.Square3 {
  grid-area: square3;
}

.Square4 {
  grid-area: square4;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-rows: 250px 800px;
  align-content: space-around;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" "leftcol rightcol";
}

.Header {
  grid-area: header;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
  align-content: space-around;
  grid-template-areas: "topheader" "bottomheader";
}

.LeftCol {
  grid-area: leftcol;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
  grid-template-areas: "square1" "square2" "square3" "square4";
}

.RightCol {
  grid-area: rightcol;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @quinlo for your reply! I tried implementing the HTML and css you provided but it seems to go full width?

Comment: No problem!  Just giving you the starting block.  If you don't want if full width just add something like:

`width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;`

to the `.container` class!

Comment: My bad buddy, my sass wasn't compiling for some reason but it's fine now, do you have any idea on how i would get the big box to sit on top of the little boxes in responsive view?

Comment: I am assuming you want the big yellow box to sit on top of the orange and green boxes?  If so, you can just adjust the grid template based on a media query.  An example would be to add this to your css:

`@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
.container {
   grid-template-columns: 100%;
   grid-template-rows: 250px 800px 800px;
   grid-template-areas: 
   "header" 
   "rightcol"
   "leftcol";
 }
}`

Comment: perfect! i can't thank you enough for your help thank you so much!

Comment: No problem happy to help!  Also, I am noticing now that there are efficiencies you can introduce, like instead of nesting two grids you can just make one grid with all of the proper elements... but you get the idea from the markup provided!  Mark as solved?

Comment: The biggest factor was getting the grid right as it was driving me crazy! You are the first person to help and i really appreciate it honestly! Next i need to figure out how to add the data in through a JS object :P